# Use Glyphicons or Font-Awesome in pdfmake prints

Tags: javascript, font-awesome, glyphicons, pdfmake

I am developing a webapp using pdfmake for the printing.
In more recent days I started using Glyphicons and Font-Awesome-Icons in my project, now I need those in the printout as well.

But I can't really imagine what would be the best way to achieve this.

I see two possibilities:

1. Include the respective Font in pdfmake and create something like a map which determines the Icons font-representation by it's class name (because this is what is used in the app). In this case I could still use the font colors for the Icons
2. I could use something like phantomJS to generate Images of the Icons, but I don't really like this idea, because I would loose the possibility to easily change the icon's color and i would have to maintain this picture collection somehow.

Any Ideas, Comments or solutions? I would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:
*(I decided to use the first approach and narrowed the icons down to use Font-Awesome only)*

1. **Find the symbol by its css-class**
   I was quite unhappy with the idea of fetching data from e.g. https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/, so I did as a co-worker suggested: I parsed the symbol directly from the stylesheet:

```js
FontAwesomeMap = {
  findSymbolForClass: findSymbolForClass
};

/**
 * Looks through all Stylesheets for css-selectors. Returns the content of the 
 * first match.
 *
 * @param   {string} selector The complete selector or part of it 
 *                            (e.g. 'user-md' for '.fa-user-md')
 * @returns {string}          The content of the 'content' attribute of the 
 *                            matching css-rule <br>
 *                            or '' if nothing has been found
 */
function findSymbolForClass(selector) {
  var result = '';
  var sheets = document.styleSheets;

  for (var sheetNr = 0; sheetNr < sheets.length; sheetNr++) {
    var content = findCSSRuleContent(sheets[sheetNr], selector);

    if (content) {
      result = stripQuotes(content);
      break;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

/**
 * Finds the first css-rule with a selectorText containing the given selector.
 *
 * @param   {CSSStyleSheet} mySheet  The stylesheet to examine
 * @param   {string}        selector The selector to match (or part of it)
 * @returns {string}                 The content of the matching rule <br>
 *                                   or '' if nothing has been found
 */
function findCSSRuleContent(mySheet, selector) {
  var ruleContent = '';
  var rules = mySheet.cssRules ? mySheet.cssRules : mySheet.rules;

  for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
    var text = rules[i].selectorText;
    if (text && text.indexOf(selector) >= 0) {
      ruleContent = rules[i].style.content;
      break;
    }
  }

  return ruleContent;
}

/**
 * Strips one leading and one trailing Character from the given String.
 *
 * The 'content'-Tag is assigned by a quoted String, which will als be returned 
 * with those quotes.
 * So we need to strip them, if we want to access the real content
 *
 * @param   {String} string original quoted content
 * @returns {String}        unquoted content
 */
function stripQuotes(string) {
  var len = string.length;
  return string.slice(1, len - 1);
}
```

2. **Import the Font in pdfMake**
   Now I had to get pdfMake to know the Font, thus I needed to convert the `.ttf` to `base64`.
   I used the `.ttf` from [github](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts) and converted it [here](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/Base64Encode/)
   Afterwards I updated the `vfs_fonts.js` as described on [github](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/wiki/Custom-Fonts---client-side):
   *(stripped the base64s)*

```js
window.pdfMake = window.pdfMake || {};
window.pdfMake.vfs = {
  "LICENSE.txt"       : "...",
  "Roboto-Italic.ttf" : "...",
  "Roboto-Medium.ttf" : "...",
  "Roboto-Regular.ttf": "...",
  "sampleImage.jpg"   : "...",
  "FontAwesome.ttf"   : "..."
};

window.pdfMake.fonts = {
  Roboto     : {
    normal     : 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
    bold       : 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
    italics    : 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
    bolditalics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf'
  },
  FontAwesome: {
    normal     : 'FontAwesome.ttf',
    bold       : 'FontAwesome.ttf',
    italics    : 'FontAwesome.ttf',
    bolditalics: 'FontAwesome.ttf'
  }
};
```

3. **Set proper style-informations**
   Last but not least, the font-information has to be set, so I made a simple style for that:

```js
styles = {
  /*...*/
  symbol: {
    font: 'FontAwesome'
  },
  /*...*/
}
```

**edit** as @nicfo pointed out, I missed to show the actual use of all together:
4. **Use the symbols in pdfmake**

```js
value = {
    text : FontAwesomeMap.findSymbolForClass(symbol) + '',
    style: ['symbol']
};
```

where the magic `FontAwesomeMap.findSymbolForClass(symbol)` ist the one mentioned above

That's all. Not exactly easy, but it's worth the effort.

I'm pretty sure the same works for Glyphicons.

Comment: i'm having the same problem at the moment, i tried your solution. after these steps, how did you include icons in the content of your pdf?

Comment: Hi PheOnix:  I had tried your solution but 'FontAwesome' not present in  pdfmake. I put these lines in vfs_fonts.js file . What i am doing wrong ?
 window.pdfMake.fonts = {
  Roboto     : {
    normal     : 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
    bold       : 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
    italics    : 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
    bolditalics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf'
  },
  FontAwesome: {
    normal     : 'FontAwesome.ttf',
    bold       : 'FontAwesome.ttf',
    italics    : 'FontAwesome.ttf',
    bolditalics: 'FontAwesome.ttf'
  }
};

Comment: @Amit did you append the base64 of FontAwesome to `window.pdfMake.vfs`?
As in 
    `window.pdfMake.vfs = {
      /* ... */
      "FontAwesome.ttf"   : "..."
    };`

Comment: yes , i had followed all the steps of above, when i check in console window.pdfMake.fonts   'FontAwesome' is present, I had also defined defaultStyle :{ font:'FontAwesome'}  , and i used it as '[&#xf047;]' one of cheat code symbol . Nothing is shown .

Comment: I have 2 suggestions:  
1: did you debug and check, what `findSymbolForClass` is finding?
2. Did you try any other symbols, ie `\f118`.  

Also I only use the Names of the Icons, not the numbers, so for example `FontAwesomeMap.findSymbolForClass('square-o')`